# Change icons controlled by a css file in other website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I download this :

http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/pop-up-login-signup-box-jquery/

You can see the demo there, and like you see :

```
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

and this is a part from the css code :

```
open:before { content: "\f07c"; }
.fa-arrows-v:before { content: "\f07d"; }
.fa-arrows-h:before { content: "\f07e"; }
.fa-bar-chart-o:before { content: "\f080"; }
.fa-twitter-square:before { content: "\f081"; }
.fa-facebook-square:before { content: "\f082"; }
.fa-camera-retro:before { content: "\f083"; }
.fa-key:before { content: "\f084"; }
.fa-gears:before,.fa-cogs:before { content: "\f085"; }
.fa-comments:before { content: "\f086"; }
.fa-thumbs-o-up:before { content: "\f087"; }
.fa-thumbs-o-down:before { content: "\f088"; }
.fa-star-half:before { content: "\f089"; }
.fa-heart-o:before { content: "\f08a"; }
.fa-sign-out:before { content: "\f08b"; }
.fa-linkedin-square:before { content: "\f08c"; }
.fa-thumb-tack:before { content: "\f08d"; }
.fa-external-link:before { content: "\f08e"; }
.fa-sign-in:before { content: "\f090"; }
.fa-trophy:before { content: "\f091"; }
.fa-github-square:before { content: "\f092"; }
.fa-upload:before { content: "\f093"; }
.fa-lemon-o:before { content: "\f094"; }
.fa-phone:before { content: "\f095"; }
.fa-square-o:before { content: "\f096"; }
.fa-bookmark-o:before { content: "\f097"; }
.fa-phone-square:before { content: "\f098"; }
.fa-twitter:before { content: "\f099"; }
.fa-facebook:before { content: "\f09a"; }
.fa-github:before { content: "\f09b"; }
.fa-unlock:before { content: "\f09c"; }
.fa-credit-card:before { content: "\f09d"; }
.fa-rss:before { content: "\f09e"; }
.fa-hdd-o:before { content: "\f0a0"; }
.fa-bullhorn:before { content: "\f0a1"; }
.fa-bell:before{content:"
```

the stylesheet is in the website and I can't find how to change that facebook and gmail icons any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: overwrite them with your own stylesheet. Use an element inspector like firebug to find out what element to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) is an icon font used to easily insert commonly used, infinitely scalable icons in a webpage. Since it's a font, you can't easily replace individual icons and still use Font Awesome. You've got a couple of options. In the example page you've linked, here is the HTML which is generating the Facebook icon:

```
<a href="#" class="social_box fb">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>
</a>
```

That `i` tag is what is creating the icon. You can either change the classes being applied to use [any of the other icons that are a part of Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), or tweak the HTML and your CSS to use your own image.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="social_box fb">
    <span class="icon facebook_icon"> </span>
    <span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
span.facebook_icon {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('images/facebook.png');
}
```

Comment: did you change the url to point to an actual image? can you share what you've done?

Comment: worked ! but you have to delete the background proprieties in style.css for facebook icon :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just remove the "fa fa-facebook/ fa fa-google-plus" class from the "i" and add your custom icons to the "i" as a background via css

> Example

`<a href="#" class="social_box">
<span class="icon"><i class="facebook-icon"></i></span>
<span class="icon_title">Connect with Facebook</span>
</a>`